# What is maximum memory size for an Apache Ignite node?

Tags: ignite, gridgain

What is the maximum memory size that an ignite node can be of?
Also I saw a blog on apache ignite which says it can be scaled well upto 1000 nodes , but that was as on May 2018. Have this number changed lately?
Also what is the biggest production cluster size for ignite /Gridgain?

Thanks,
Anuja

Answer (score 1):

There's no hard-coded memory limit. But there are practical limits. For example, the more memory you have in a single node, the longer it will take to recover from a node failure.

There are certainly clusters with many thousands of nodes, though I don't have an exact number to hand.